# How to make that bottomSheet not to cover or I can get height of BottomSheet?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use BottomSheet as Footer but BottomSheet hide other container from body?

I think about 2 ways.

First way, Getting height of the BottomSheet and calculate

```
...
     return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - bottomSheetSize
      children: [
      Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: listView,
        )
      ),
...
```

or second way, the BottomSheet doesn't cover a body

I don't know how to get size of the BottomSheet or not to cover body.

Can you help me with one of option?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do anything in the current screen if you open bottom sheets. If you are making a footer type of thing, use another container at the bottom of the first container wrapped in a column or use Stack and stack the footer on top of the first container.

Comment: I don't use bottomSheet widget, I want to use this ```Scaffold( bottomSheet: Container(height: 100));```